# How can i export my flutter app's datas to Word ducument?

Tags: android, flutter, export, docx

This is a general question about Flutter Android App. I have just finished my examination app but i do wanna add Word export feature on it.

For e.g.
I have a list in my app that containes with network images and text datas together comes from firebase database and i wanna export this list as a Word document. I havent seen this feature till now so is this possible? Can i do it standart packages in flutter or Is there any specific package to do it?

If there is someone here did it before or gets any idea please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package to generate docx file, please check here [docx_template](https://pub.dev/packages/docx_template)